# Как отобразить значение на всех страницах

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть вот такой код

```
public PartialViewResult Balance()
{
     var balance = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault();
     return PartialView(balance);
}
```

В контроллере Home

Так же есть страница Balance

```
@model ApplicationUser

<div class="navbar-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index", "Home",
        new { @class = "btn btn-default navbar-btn" })
</div>

<div>
    <b>Ваш баланс: </b>

    Личный номер: <b >@Model.Code</b>,

    Ваш баланс: @Model.Balance
</div>
```

Если выводишь через

```
 <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Balance">Баланс</a></li>
```

Как ссылку, то при переходе всё работает! А, мне нужно это информацию поместить в navbar не ссылкой, а так что бы отображались значения, как при переходе по ссылке.

**Помогите.**

В Asp.Net framework это можно было сделать с помощью

```
@Html.Action("Balance", "Home")
```

А как это сделать в Core не пойму.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `View Component`

Comment: @WebMorda Я про это читал но не понял как его использовать на моём примере. Не подскажешь?

Comment: @WebMorda Ну вроде разобрался! Спасибо!